# Commerce form refresh: 500 error on /en/system/ajax

Tags: 7, commerce

Where can I find more information about this error? Nothing is appearing in logs, the error message itself has no useful data.

```
An AJAX HTTP error occurred. 
HTTP Result Code: 500 Debugging information follows. 
Path: /en/system/ajax 
StatusText: Service unavailable (with message)
```

Some background info:

Just grasping at straws this point, and may actually completely rework how this feature will work, but just in case anyone has any bright ideas:

Product variations exist in Commerce, certain options refresh the form via Ajax (this is a built-in commerce function), and on refresh any attribute/field that is no longer available is not included with the refreshed form. Again, total standard Commerce function.

I have used a few modules to help me create variations, such as Bulk Product Creation, and as recently has 1 month ago used the exact same process to do this successfully. That product is still working.

When I inspect the ajax call itself there's nothing really unique to this vs. the other working product(s).

I have tried eliminating variations, increasing PHP memory/POST stuff, etc., and have also turned on full error reporting.

Answer (score 1):

Answering my own question so my stupidity is saved for all to learn from.

More details can be found in the "Reports" section of the site.

I have now resolved my issue, and it was a line of code in a custom module we made.